# How can I clear form values after successful form submission using Codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

In **codeigniter 3** i use  `$this->form_validation->clear_field_data();` to clear my form values after successful form submission.
nom i'm on **codeigniter 4** and the fonction do not work anymore. can some one help me with this task.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you do when you submit the form?
If you reload the form after submit, the values must be empty.

Or are you setting the values in your code?